# Open XML - How to add a watermark to a docx document

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I'm trying to take an existing document and if a header doesn't exist, create one, and then add a watermark to the header that says "DRAFT" diagonally.  I've followed an example posted [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/c7c92ca7-94bf-4af3-822d-0b5965f3e5d5/?prof=required) and I've gotten the code to the point where it will add the watermark if the header already exists.

The current issue is when I add a new header, add the reference to the document, and then add the watermark to the header, the document becomes corrupt and can no longer open in Word 2010.

To test I've been doing the following:  Create a new word document from word itself with text of "TestDoc" in the main part of the page.  Save to my desktop as "TestDoc.docx" and close the file.  Then I run the app from Visual Studio.  The code below will always make it corrupted.  If I add a header to the file with no text in it and then hit save, the watermark will be displayed correctly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Office;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using HorizontalAnchorValues = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Wordprocessing.HorizontalAnchorValues;
using Lock = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Office.Lock;
using VerticalAnchorValues = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Wordprocessing.VerticalAnchorValues;

namespace DocumentWatermarkTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\loggedinuser\Desktop\TestDoc.docx", true);
            AddWatermark(doc);
            doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        }

        static Header MakeHeader()
        {
            var header = new Header();
            var paragraph = new Paragraph();
            var run = new Run();
            var text = new Text();
            text.Text = "";
            run.Append(text);
            paragraph.Append(run);
            header.Append(paragraph);
            return header;
        }

        static void AddWatermark(WordprocessingDocument doc)
        {
            if (doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.Count() == 0)
            {
                doc.MainDocumentPart.DeleteParts(doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts);
                var newHeaderPart = doc.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
                var rId = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(newHeaderPart);
                var headerRef = new HeaderReference();
                headerRef.Id = rId;
                var sectionProps = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>().LastOrDefault();
                if (sectionProps == null)
                {
                    sectionProps = new SectionProperties();
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProps);
                }
                sectionProps.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
                sectionProps.Append(headerRef);

                newHeaderPart.Header = MakeHeader();
                newHeaderPart.Header.Save();
            }

            foreach (HeaderPart headerPart in doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
            {
                var sdtBlock1 = new SdtBlock();
                var sdtProperties1 = new SdtProperties();
                var sdtId1 = new SdtId() { Val = 87908844 };
                var sdtContentDocPartObject1 = new DocPartObjectSdt();
                var docPartGallery1 = new DocPartGallery() { Val = "Watermarks" };
                var docPartUnique1 = new DocPartUnique();
                sdtContentDocPartObject1.Append(docPartGallery1);
                sdtContentDocPartObject1.Append(docPartUnique1);
                sdtProperties1.Append(sdtId1);
                sdtProperties1.Append(sdtContentDocPartObject1);

                var sdtContentBlock1 = new SdtContentBlock();
                var paragraph2 = new Paragraph()
                                     {
                                         RsidParagraphAddition = "00656E18",
                                         RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00656E18"
                                     };
                var paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();
                var paragraphStyleId2 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };
                paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphStyleId2);
                var run1 = new Run();
                var runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
                var noProof1 = new NoProof();
                var languages1 = new Languages() { EastAsia = "zh-TW" };
                runProperties1.Append(noProof1);
                runProperties1.Append(languages1);
                var picture1 = new Picture();
                var shapetype1 = new Shapetype()
                                     {
                                         Id = "_x0000_t136",
                                         CoordinateSize = "21600,21600",
                                         OptionalNumber = 136,
                                         Adjustment = "10800",
                                         EdgePath = "m@7,l@8,m@5,21600l@6,21600e"
                                     };
                var formulas1 = new Formulas();
                var formula1 = new Formula() { Equation = "sum #0 0 10800" };
                var formula2 = new Formula() { Equation = "prod #0 2 1" };
                var formula3 = new Formula() { Equation = "sum 21600 0 @1" };
                var formula4 = new Formula() { Equation = "sum 0 0 @2" };
                var formula5 = new Formula() { Equation = "sum 21600 0 @3" };
                var formula6 = new Formula() { Equation = "if @0 @3 0" };
                var formula7 = new Formula() { Equation = "if @0 21600 @1" };
                var formula8 = new Formula() { Equation = "if @0 0 @2" };
                var formula9 = new Formula() { Equation = "if @0 @4 21600" };
                var formula10 = new Formula() { Equation = "mid @5 @6" };
                var formula11 = new Formula() { Equation = "mid @8 @5" };
                var formula12 = new Formula() { Equation = "mid @7 @8" };
                var formula13 = new Formula() { Equation = "mid @6 @7" };
                var formula14 = new Formula() { Equation = "sum @6 0 @5" };

                formulas1.Append(formula1);
                formulas1.Append(formula2);
                formulas1.Append(formula3);
                formulas1.Append(formula4);
                formulas1.Append(formula5);
                formulas1.Append(formula6);
                formulas1.Append(formula7);
                formulas1.Append(formula8);
                formulas1.Append(formula9);
                formulas1.Append(formula10);
                formulas1.Append(formula11);
                formulas1.Append(formula12);
                formulas1.Append(formula13);
                formulas1.Append(formula14);
                var path1 = new Path()
                {
                    AllowTextPath = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.BooleanValues.True,
                    ConnectionPointType = ConnectValues.Custom,
                    ConnectionPoints = "@9,0;@10,10800;@11,21600;@12,10800",
                    ConnectAngles = "270,180,90,0"
                };
                var textPath1 = new TextPath()
                {
                    On = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.BooleanValues.True,
                    FitShape = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.BooleanValues.True
                };
                var shapeHandles1 = new Handles();

                var shapeHandle1 = new Handle()
                                       {
                                           Position = "#0,bottomRight",
                                           XRange = "6629,14971"
                                       };

                shapeHandles1.Append(shapeHandle1);

                var lock1 = new Lock
                {
                    Extension = ExtensionHandlingBehaviorValues.Edit,
                    TextLock = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Office.BooleanValues.True,
                    ShapeType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Office.BooleanValues.True
                };

                shapetype1.Append(formulas1);
                shapetype1.Append(path1);
                shapetype1.Append(textPath1);
                shapetype1.Append(shapeHandles1);
                shapetype1.Append(lock1);
                var shape1 = new Shape()
                                 {
                                     Id = "PowerPlusWaterMarkObject357476642",
                                     Style = "position:absolute;left:0;text-align:left;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:527.85pt;height:131.95pt;rotation:315;z-index:-251656192;mso-position-horizontal:center;mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin;mso-position-vertical:center;mso-position-vertical-relative:margin",
                                     OptionalString = "_x0000_s2049",
                                     AllowInCell = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.BooleanValues.False,
                                     FillColor = "silver",
                                     Stroked = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.BooleanValues.False,
                                     Type = "#_x0000_t136"
                                 };


                var fill1 = new Fill() { Opacity = ".5" };
                TextPath textPath2 = new TextPath()
                                         {
                                             Style = "font-family:\"Calibri\";font-size:1pt",
                                             String = "DRAFT"
                                         };

                var textWrap1 = new TextWrap()
                                    {
                                        AnchorX = HorizontalAnchorValues.Margin,
                                        AnchorY = VerticalAnchorValues.Margin
                                    };

                shape1.Append(fill1);
                shape1.Append(textPath2);
                shape1.Append(textWrap1);
                picture1.Append(shapetype1);
                picture1.Append(shape1);
                run1.Append(runProperties1);
                run1.Append(picture1);
                paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
                paragraph2.Append(run1);
                sdtContentBlock1.Append(paragraph2);
                sdtBlock1.Append(sdtProperties1);
                sdtBlock1.Append(sdtContentBlock1);
                headerPart.Header.Append(sdtBlock1);
                headerPart.Header.Save();
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This is now resolved by changing the way the file is opened up.  When we change the Main function to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\loggedinuser\Desktop\TestDoc.docx", true);
            //AddWatermark(doc);
            //doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            byte[] sourceBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\loggedinuser\Desktop\TestDoc.docx");

            MemoryStream inMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            inMemoryStream.Write(sourceBytes, 0, (int)sourceBytes.Length);

            var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inMemoryStream, true);
            AddWatermark(doc);
            doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

            doc.Close();
            doc.Dispose();
            doc = null;

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\loggedinuser\Desktop\TestDoc.docx", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                inMemoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
            }

            inMemoryStream.Close();
            inMemoryStream.Dispose();
            inMemoryStream = null;
        }
```

The document now correctly opens in word.  Thanks Brad!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now resolved by changing the way the file is opened up. When we change the Main function to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\loggedinuser\Desktop\TestDoc.docx", true);
    //AddWatermark(doc);
    //doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    byte[] sourceBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\loggedinuser\Desktop\TestDoc.docx");
    MemoryStream inMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    inMemoryStream.Write(sourceBytes, 0, (int)sourceBytes.Length);

    var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inMemoryStream, true);
    AddWatermark(doc);
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

    doc.Close();
    doc.Dispose();
    doc = null;

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\loggedinuser\Desktop\TestDoc.docx", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        inMemoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
    }

    inMemoryStream.Close();
    inMemoryStream.Dispose();
    inMemoryStream = null;
}
```

The document now correctly opens in word. Thanks to Brad B. a coworker at Sonoma Partners for finding this!

Answer (score 1):

remove the line

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.DeleteParts(doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts);
```

AND replace the check for sectionproperties with something similar to

```
if (doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>().Count == 0)
```

EDIT:

the complete if then.. would look like this:

```
var sectionProps = null;

if (doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>().Count == 0)
{
sectionProps = new SectionProperties();
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProps);
}
else
{
sectionProps = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>().Last();
}
```

Comment: When I make the changes, it skips the if statement you proposed above and gives me the following error: The file TestDoc.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.  details: Microsoft Office cannot open this file because some parts are missing or invalid.  Location: Part: /word/document.xml, Line: 1, Column: 0

Comment: I've made the changes and I'm still getting the error.  Should I edit the code above to include your suggested changes?

Comment: sorry that it didn't help :-( I don't think that you should edit the code above.

Comment: We've found the answer.  The way we were opening the document was causing the issue.  when the the main function is changed to what is above it works.

Comment: I don't understand why it makes a difference... but glad that you solved it :-)

Comment: I used the above code to add watermark. It adds watermark from second page onwards and skips the first page altogether. When I look at the count of doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderPart there is one less header. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Replace `var sectionProps = null;` with `SectionProperties sectionProps;`