# DocPartObjectSdt() not found

Tags: c#, reference, openxml, using, docx

I've got some problem with the `DocPartObjectSdt()`. The VS say "The type or namespace name 'DocPartObjectSdt' could not be found..." and I didn't found relevant solution in the google...

I copied the code from here: [Open XML - How to add a watermark to a docx document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002341/open-xml-how-to-add-a-watermark-to-a-docx-document/)
And I copied the usings too, but I've got this problem.

Someone said I have to open new Question about this problem, thats why I did that :)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context in which it is used in the example code, what you're looking for is `SdtContentDocPartObject`. Look at ["MSDN: SdtContentDocPartObject Class"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sdtcontentdocpartobject.aspx) and see if that is what you need.